# iPod touch compared to iPhone 4 as a development platform (iOS 4.1)

Tags: iphone, ios4, ipod-touch

I would like to revamp an old question, concerning the development of apps on the iPod touch as a cheap replacement for the iPhone:

[iPod Touch compared to iPhone as development platform for iPhone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128245/ipod-touch-compared-to-iphone-as-development-platform-for-iphone-apps)

Now Apple has released the new iPod touch with Retina display and the iPhone 4, both with iOS 4.1.

Should I choose the new iPod touch as a development device instead of the iPhone 4, which differences would I encouter, apart from the phone feature of course?

Comment: Good on you for rebooting an old question with a new one to account for the latest technologies! Shows just how fast things are moving these days :)

Comment: If you want to test an app requiring camera resolution above VGA, or vibration, or handling incoming phone call interruptions, or switching between 2 built-in speakers, or GPS accuracy or location acquisition far from any wifi access points, or calibrating colors over a wide viewing angle, then you may want to consider an iPhone 4.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I forgot about the lack of vibration unit, good catch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The differences are only substantial if your app would otherwise make use of them:

Compared to the iPhone 4, the new iPod Touch:

- has less RAM, 256MB vs 512MB,
- has a lower-quality rear camera,
- doesn't have a GPS unit,
- has a lower-quality retina display,
- doesn't have a vibration unit,
- and obviously doesn't have a phone radio unit.

Since most apps don't use the camera or the GPS, that's probably not a big deal. The retina display difference is also pretty minor (from what I've read). The difference most likely to give you grief is the amount of RAM, especially if you are making a game, but since you're talking about developing on the iPod Touch and not the iPhone 4, you're probably safe, since what works with less RAM should work when there's more RAM available.

Comment: The Retina Display on the iTouch and iPhone are both 960x640-pixel resolution at 326 ppi

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, but (I've read that) the iPod Touch's is not an IPS retina display. SO while they share many of the same specs, they are not identical screens.

Comment: Ok, but IPS doesn't affect developer side of things whereas the PPI and resolution do. Doesn't no IPS mean that it will look funny when landscape.

Comment: If your app requires or does color calibration, then IPS may be required for development and test.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the difference is the phone has more features. GPS, phone, and compass IIRC. If you plan on making an app that is both for the Touch and Phone, then there wouldn't be a difference. If you plan on taking advantage of the phone, go for the phone.

Answer (score 0):

The iPod touch is an excellent development device. Less expensive than an iPhone and easy to get. And now with the fourth generation also much closer to the iPhone.